# margin-top and mouse hover are not working properly

Tags: html, css

Here is the aspx file:

```
<div class="courses">
                <h1>Courses</h1>
                <div class="courselist">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="webcrsebtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/frontendbtnbgc.jpg" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="reactntivebtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/reactnativebtnbgc.jpg" />
                </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the corrosponding css:

```
.courses
{
    height: 100px;
}
.courses h1
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    color:#548DD4;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.courselist
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.courselist #webcrsebtn
{

    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.courselist #webcrsebtn:hover
{
    margin-top:0px;
}
.courselist #reactntivebtn
{
    margin-top:20px;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.courselist #reactntivebtn:hover
{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Here is the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w433i.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL7xm.jpg)

When I am giving margin-top in one ImageButton it automatically applies to another ImageButton. In mouse hover margin-top: 0px is not working.

I am trying to do when mouse hovers the ImageButton moves in upper direction.

Comment: Look at the heights of `.courses` and `.courselist`. Please set up a fiddle with links to the images. And this is not an asp.net issue.

Comment: If I understand, you need to add `margin-top:20px;` to `.courselist #webcrsebtn`, so they're the same?? I don't get the problem. Try to reproduce it.

Comment: adding margin-top in both ImageButton or adding one imagebutton it gives same result

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out what your problem/question is.

Comment: I am adding margin-pad in one imageButton so why this margin-top property automatically applies to another imagebutton

Comment: and on mouse hover I set margin-top:0px means Imagebutton changes its position in upword direction.But It si not changing its position

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/ad6g2woq/80/

Comment: here mouse hover is only working on 2nd Image.I want If mouse hovers on first image it changes its position and another image willbe fixed and same thing will happen on 2nd image also

Comment: I see what you mean. Someone else jump in if poss. I don't know what's causing that.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Images and other elements that are `display:inline-block` vertically align off each other. Check out their `vertical-align` property, you will see by default this is set to `baseline`. If you adjust the top margin of one element it will affect the other.

By using `float` you remove the elements from the normal document flow and make them independent.

```css
.courses {
    /*height: 100px;*/
}

.courses h1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    color: #548DD4;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.courselist {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.courselist #webcrsebtn {
    
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*NEW - float*/
    float:left;
}

.courselist #webcrsebtn:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.courselist #reactntivebtn {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*NEW - float*/
    float:left;
}

.courselist #reactntivebtn:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="courses">
    <h1>Courses</h1>
    <div class="courselist">
        <img ID="webcrsebtn" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
        <img ID="reactntivebtn" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

On a side note I would consider consolidating your CSS some what using classes. This example also has the hover effect on both buttons.

```css
.courses {
    /*height: 100px;*/
}

.courses h1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    color: #548DD4;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.courselist {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.courselist .imgButton {
    margin-top: 20px;
     height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*NEW - float*/
    float:left;
}


.courselist .imgButton:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="courses">
    <h1>Courses</h1>
    <div class="courselist">
        <img ID="webcrsebtn" class="imgButton" src="https://fillmurray.com/250/250" />
        <img ID="reactntivebtn" class="imgButton" src="https://fillmurray.com/g/250/250" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, from the way your question was phrased and with the code supplied I thought that the first image was meant to be offset. My second example now has the hover effect working.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot say why the margin-top property isn't working - this one baffled me.  However, you could use `postion: relative;` along with `top: 20px;` and `:hover { top: 0; }`

HTML:

```
<div class="courses">
    <h1>Courses</h1>
    <div class="courselist">
        <image ID="webcrsebtn" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
        <image ID="reactntivebtn" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.courses {
    /*height: 100px;*/
}

.courses h1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    color: #548DD4;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.courselist {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#webcrsebtn {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

#webcrsebtn:hover {
    top: 0px;
}

#reactntivebtn {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 00px 4px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

#reactntivebtn:hover {
    top: 0px;
}
```

and here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ad6g2woq/107/)